# Testing Someone Android app using Facebook login in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, facebook-login, credentials

Is there any way to test or log-in an android app which is using the Facebook login in emulator whose owner is someone else without using your own original credentials?
If possible, How to do it?
If not, why not?